# Arduino Project - Social Distancing Alarm Ultrasonic Raidar Project

Tags: c++, arduino, project, arduino-uno

For the past few days, I have been trying to make a code for the project I have written for the title for a science project, but after trying to find a perfect code on the internet, I found it impossible to do. I am thinking of using a radar-like moving ultrasonic sensor with an LCD screen to display the distance and a buzzer to warn the person if he/she isn't maintaining social distancing. The problem is on the internet there is either no code with an LCD screen and radar movement at the same time. I was wondering if anyone can help me combine these codes together?

Here is the code with a lcd screen, buzzer, but no radar:

```
#include <HCSR04.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#define trigPin 7
#define echoPin 6
#define buzzer 9
#define backlight 10

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 8);
UltraSonicDistanceSensor distanceSensor(trigPin, echoPin);

int tempReading;
double tempK;
float tempC;
int rounded;
int temp_round;
volatile boolean modes = 0;
double distance;

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  attachInterrupt(0, changeMode, FALLING);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(backlight, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(backlight, HIGH);
  backlightOn();
}

void loop() {
  tempReading = analogRead(A0);
  tempK = log(10000.0 * ((1024.0 / tempReading - 1)));
  tempK = 1 / (0.001129148 + (0.000234125 + (0.0000000876741 * tempK * tempK )) * tempK );
  tempC = tempK - 273.15;
  distance = distanceSensor.measureDistanceCm(tempC);
  temp_round = round(tempC);
  if (modes == 1) {
    backlightOn();
    if (distance >= 300 || distance <= 0) {
      rounded = 0;
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("Out of range");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print("Temperature:" + String(temp_round) + " C");
    }
    else {
      rounded = round(distance);
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("Distance: ");
      lcd.print(rounded);
      lcd.print(" cm");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print("Temperature:" + String(temp_round) + " C");
    }
  } else {
    if (distance >= 300 || distance <= 0) {
      rounded = 0;
      lcd.clear();
      backlightOff();
    }
    else {
      rounded = round(distance);
      if (distance >= 200) {
        backlightOff();
        lcd.clear();
      }
      else if (distance <= 200 && distance > 100) {
        backlightOn();
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("Please keep away");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Distance:");
        lcd.print(rounded);
        lcd.print(" cm");
      }
      else if (distance <= 100 && distance > 50) {
        backlightOn();
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("Keep away");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Distance:");
        lcd.print(rounded);
        lcd.print(" cm");
        delay(200);
        buzz();
        backlightOff();
        delay(100);
        unbuzz();
        backlightOn();
        delay(100);
      }
      else if (distance <= 50) {
        backlightOn();
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("STAY AWAY!");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Distance:");
        lcd.print(rounded);
        lcd.print(" cm");
        delay(200);
        buzz();
        backlightOff();
        delay(200);
        unbuzz();
        backlightOn();
        delay(200);
        buzz();
        backlightOff();
        delay(200);
        unbuzz();
        backlightOn();
      }
    }
  }
  delay(700);
}

void changeMode() {
  modes = !modes;
}

void backlightOn() {
  digitalWrite(backlight, HIGH);
}

void backlightOff() {
  digitalWrite(backlight, LOW);
}

void buzz() {
  digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
}

void unbuzz() {
  digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
}
```

and here is the code for a radar

```
#include <Servo.h>. 
// Defines Tirg and Echo pins of the Ultrasonic Sensor
const int trigPin = 10;
const int echoPin = 11;
// Variables for the duration and the distance
long duration;
int distance;
Servo myServo; // Creates a servo object for controlling the servo motor
void setup() {
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myServo.attach(12); // Defines on which pin is the servo motor attached
}
void loop() {
  // rotates the servo motor from 15 to 165 degrees
  for(int i=15;i<=165;i++){  
  myServo.write(i);
  delay(30);
  distance = calculateDistance();// Calls a function for calculating the distance measured by the Ultrasonic sensor for each degree
  
  Serial.print(i); // Sends the current degree into the Serial Port
  Serial.print(","); // Sends addition character right next to the previous value needed later in the Processing IDE for indexing
  Serial.print(distance); // Sends the distance value into the Serial Port
  Serial.print("."); // Sends addition character right next to the previous value needed later in the Processing IDE for indexing
  }
  // Repeats the previous lines from 165 to 15 degrees
  for(int i=165;i>15;i--){  
  myServo.write(i);
  delay(30);
  distance = calculateDistance();
  Serial.print(i);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(distance);
  Serial.print(".");
  }
}
// Function for calculating the distance measured by the Ultrasonic sensor
int calculateDistance(){ 
  
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); 
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH); 
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH); // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
  distance= duration*0.034/2;
  return distance;
}
```

If someone can combine these two to make a program that has all radar movement, LCD screen, buzz, I would be really grateful.

Comment: Consider the fact that a screen displays *something* and a sensor senses *something*. In each case, the information has to *go* or *come* from somewhere. With that said, you should consider the screen a secondary place to put information - you need to keep it in variables too. First capture (measure) a distance, then simply display it.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is. The code is a bit redundant :), but you can solve it if you want. Regardless, it must work.

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

#define buzzer 9
#define backlight 10

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 8);

// Defines Tirg and Echo pins of the Ultrasonic Sensor
const int trigPin = 10;
const int echoPin = 11;

// Variables for the duration and the distance
int tempReading;
double tempK;
float tempC;
int rounded;
int temp_round;
volatile boolean modes = 0;
long duration;
int distance;

Servo myServo; // Creates a servo object for controlling the servo motor

void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
  
  myServo.attach(14); // Defines on which pin is the servo motor attached
  
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  attachInterrupt(0, changeMode, FALLING);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(backlight, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(backlight, HIGH);
  backlightOn();
}

void loop() {
  
  // rotates the servo motor from 15 to 165 degrees
  for(int i=15;i<=165;i++){  
    myServo.write(i);
    delay(30);
    distance = calculateDistance();// Calls a function for calculating the distance measured by the Ultrasonic sensor for each degree
    tempReading = analogRead(A0);
    tempK = log(10000.0 * ((1024.0 / tempReading - 1)));
    tempK = 1 / (0.001129148 + (0.000234125 + (0.0000000876741 * tempK * tempK )) * tempK );
    tempC = tempK - 273.15;
    temp_round = round(tempC);
    if (modes == 1) {
      backlightOn();
      if (distance >= 300 || distance <= 0) {
        rounded = 0;
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("Out of range");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Temperature:" + String(temp_round) + " C");
      }
      else {
        rounded = round(distance);
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("Distance: ");
        lcd.print(rounded);
        lcd.print(" cm");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Temperature:" + String(temp_round) + " C");
      }
    } else {
      if (distance >= 300 || distance <= 0) {
        rounded = 0;
        lcd.clear();
        backlightOff();
      }
      else {
        rounded = round(distance);
        if (distance >= 200) {
          backlightOff();
          lcd.clear();
        }
        else if (distance <= 200 && distance > 100) {
          backlightOn();
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.print("Please keep away");
          lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
          lcd.print("Distance:");
          lcd.print(rounded);
          lcd.print(" cm");
        }
        else if (distance <= 100 && distance > 50) {
          backlightOn();
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.print("Keep away");
          lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
          lcd.print("Distance:");
          lcd.print(rounded);
          lcd.print(" cm");
          delay(200);
          buzz();
          backlightOff();
          delay(100);
          unbuzz();
          backlightOn();
          delay(100);
        }
        else if (distance <= 50) {
          backlightOn();
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.print("STAY AWAY!");
          lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
          lcd.print("Distance:");
          lcd.print(rounded);
          lcd.print(" cm");
          delay(200);
          buzz();
          backlightOff();
          delay(200);
          unbuzz();
          backlightOn();
          delay(200);
          buzz();
          backlightOff();
          delay(200);
          unbuzz();
          backlightOn();
        }
      }
    }
    Serial.print(i); // Sends the current degree into the Serial Port
    Serial.print(","); // Sends addition character right next to the previous value needed later in the Processing IDE for indexing
    Serial.print(distance); // Sends the distance value into the Serial Port
    Serial.print("."); // Sends addition character right next to the previous value needed later in the Processing IDE for indexing
  }
  
  // Repeats the previous lines from 165 to 15 degrees
  for(int i=165;i>15;i--){  
    myServo.write(i);
    delay(30);
    distance = calculateDistance();
    tempReading = analogRead(A0);
    tempK = log(10000.0 * ((1024.0 / tempReading - 1)));
    tempK = 1 / (0.001129148 + (0.000234125 + (0.0000000876741 * tempK * tempK )) * tempK );
    tempC = tempK - 273.15;
    temp_round = round(tempC);
    if (modes == 1) {
      backlightOn();
      if (distance >= 300 || distance <= 0) {
        rounded = 0;
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("Out of range");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Temperature:" + String(temp_round) + " C");
      }
      else {
        rounded = round(distance);
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("Distance: ");
        lcd.print(rounded);
        lcd.print(" cm");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Temperature:" + String(temp_round) + " C");
      }
    } else {
      if (distance >= 300 || distance <= 0) {
        rounded = 0;
        lcd.clear();
        backlightOff();
      }
      else {
        rounded = round(distance);
        if (distance >= 200) {
          backlightOff();
          lcd.clear();
        }
        else if (distance <= 200 && distance > 100) {
          backlightOn();
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.print("Please keep away");
          lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
          lcd.print("Distance:");
          lcd.print(rounded);
          lcd.print(" cm");
        }
        else if (distance <= 100 && distance > 50) {
          backlightOn();
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.print("Keep away");
          lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
          lcd.print("Distance:");
          lcd.print(rounded);
          lcd.print(" cm");
          delay(200);
          buzz();
          backlightOff();
          delay(100);
          unbuzz();
          backlightOn();
          delay(100);
        }
        else if (distance <= 50) {
          backlightOn();
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.print("STAY AWAY!");
          lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
          lcd.print("Distance:");
          lcd.print(rounded);
          lcd.print(" cm");
          delay(200);
          buzz();
          backlightOff();
          delay(200);
          unbuzz();
          backlightOn();
          delay(200);
          buzz();
          backlightOff();
          delay(200);
          unbuzz();
          backlightOn();
        }
      }
    }
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(distance);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
}
// Function for calculating the distance measured by the Ultrasonic sensor
int calculateDistance(){ 
  
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); 
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH); 
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH); // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
  distance= duration*0.034/2;
  return distance;
}
void changeMode() {
  modes = !modes;
}

void backlightOn() {
  digitalWrite(backlight, HIGH);
}

void backlightOff() {
  digitalWrite(backlight, LOW);
}

void buzz() {
  digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
}

void unbuzz() {
  digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I can finally catch up in my project!